# Collect 'unusual' examples of real-valued functions

Tags: real-analysis, functions, reference-request, soft-question, examples-counterexamples

I am trying to collect research papers, articles and books which contain 'weird' or 'unusual' examples of real-valued function.

An example of research paper is

[A Counterexample and an Exact Versoin of Fatou's Lemma in Infinite Dimension](https://conservancy.umn.edu/bitstream/handle/11299/55505/1986-235.pdf?sequence=1)

An example of article is

[Some counterexamples on the behaviour of real-valued
functions and their derivatives](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1302.1065.pdf)

Examples of books are

[Surprises and Counterexamples in Real Function Theory](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/8185931712)

Analysis in examples and counterexamples. An introduction to the theory
of real functions

[Counterexamples in Analysis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486428753)

> Question: Can someone provide me more articles and books which are similar to the above? My aim is to learn as many function construction techniques as possible.

Comment: Phrase-google my name "Dave L. Renfro" along with various words and phrases, such as [nowhere continuous](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Dave+L+Renfro%22+%22nowhere+continuous%22&filter=0) OR [everywhere discontinuous](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Dave+L+Renfro%22+%22everywhere%20discontinuous%22&filter=0) OR [nowhere differentiable](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Dave+L+Renfro%22+%22nowhere+differentiable%22&filter=0) OR [nowhere monotone](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Dave+L+Renfro%22+%22nowhere%20monotone%22&filter=0), etc.

Comment: There is an [examples-counterexamples](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/examples-counterexamples) tag.

Comment: @KeithMcClary: Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 10):

You may be interested in an example of a *strictly positive* real-valued function with *zero* Lebesgue integral in a model of Zermelo-Fraenkel set theory [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.00493).

Answer (score 6):

> A course of lectures entitled *Some Pathological Functions in Real Analysis* was held by A.B. Karazishvili in 1997 - 1998.
>
> - His book *[Strange Functions in Real Analysis](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00UVB40QS)* is based upon these lecture notes. Browsing the preface and the table of contents should give a first impression.
>
>   Theorems, examples and exercises are often linked with corresponding references into the bibliography pointing to their origin.
>
> This *[AMS review](http://euro-math-soc.eu/review/strange-functions-real-analysis-second-edition)* might be helpful.

Comment: @Idonknow: Thanks a lot for granting the bounty! :-)